# No linkage at block scope?

Tags: c++, static, extern, linkage

Do all variables declared in a block have 'no linkage'?

For example:

#### 1:

If I declare a static variable:

```
void foo()
{
   static int i;
}
```

Would it have an internal linkage or no linkage? If no linkage, then why make it static?

#### 2:

What happens if I use extern?

```
/*global scope*/
static int i;

void foo()
{
    extern int i;
}
```

In this case, what will be the linkage of `i`?

Answer (score 6):

Indeed, 'no linkage' at function scope.

The goal is *lifetime* management: the static has the *lifetime* of a global static, while it has the *visibility* (scope) of a local.

**Note**

In C++ you can also declare statics ('globals') without linkage by enclosing them inside an anonymous namespace. This trick is used commonly in header-only libraries:

```
namespace /*anon*/
{
    void foo() {}    // only in this translation unit
    int answer = 42; // this too
}
```

> What happens if I use `extern`?

If you use extern, the declaration is an `extern` declaration only (nothing is *defined*). As such, it normally would be expected to *external linkage* by definition - being defined in another translation unit. (So it acts the same as if when it was declared at global scope). This is similar to local function declarations:

```
int main()
{
    void exit(int); // equivalent to non-local declaration
}
```

Note that, in your **`2.`** example, variable `i` was already declared `static` and it will therefore not get external linkage. I might get declared in another translation unit without linker conflicts, though.

Comment: "As such, it has external linkage by definition" -- The funny thing is that `extern` doesn't automatically mean external linkage. It does mean name has a linkage, but it can be internal, like in the original example.

Comment: @ sehe -- #2, where `extern` is used, it actually defines name with internal linkage.

Comment: @GeneBushuyev: yup, I was slightly confused there. Have updated my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. "Would it have internal linkage or no linkage? if no linkage then why make it static?" -- it would have no linkage. `static` specifies the static storage duration.
2. "What happens if i use extern?" It will be a declaration of a name with external linkage, and since there is none in global scope, the program will report linkage errors. **Edit:** Since there is a previous `static` declaration visible in the scope, the standard says the name "receives the linkage of the previous declaration" 3.5/6, so the `i` inside `foo()` will have internal linkage.

Comment: You mean his second code snippet will have link errors? It worked fine for me

Comment: @Michael Mrozek - "It worked fine for me" is never an answer. What's important is what the standard says. I must say I overlooked previous `static`, so I'm editing my response.